# FIND_IN_SET not retrieving results (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, find-in-set

I am troubles with this method not returning results. There are ids within 'table' that match the array. I guess it's not liking something, except I cannot quite put my finger on it.

```
$define = ",8,9,10,";

// ** Data Retrieve ** // 
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$query_data = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$define."', id)";
$data = mysql_query($query_data, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
$totalRows_data = mysql_num_rows($data);
```

Comment: You have the arguments reversed to `FIND_IN_SET()`.  The target value is first, and the list second. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: But in this instance, since your column is `id` in the database and your set is user-supplied, this is more appropriately done with an `IN()`.  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (8,9,10)`

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski I was thinking that that might be the crux of it, I tried the IN command though had my commas in the wrong place. Really appreciate your feedback / insight.

Comment: would you like me to formulate an answer?

Comment: Would be great to give you the points if you want them. Else, I can draw it up.

Comment: Go ahead and answer for yourself. I don't need the points.

Comment: Its discouraged to use mysql as its deprecated

Answer (score 0):

In FIND_IN_SET the target value is first, and the list second. So, the query should be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,'".$define."');
```